# JQL search on email id JIRA

Tags: jira, jql

How do i list the users whose email address is like @gmail.com

SQL Query equivalent to it :

select a.user_name,a.email_address
from cwd_user a 
where a.email_address like '%@gmail.com%';

Need a JQL query similar to that, as i am trying to create a filter to list all users part of email address (@gmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

The result of a JQL query is always a set of issues, not a set of users, so you cannot accomplish what you want with JQL.

If you meant that you were looking for issues whose reporter or assignee fell within a certain email domain, look at the [JIRA Toolkit Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.toolkit) and the custom fields you can then add for Domain of Reporter or Domain of Assignee. You can then search those custom fields directly with JQL (after doing a reindex).

If you are truly just looking for users and not issues, but you are willing to loosen up your question from requiring JQL, you can also try the [users REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4099) to search by substring. However, this will produce results in JSON, and it's a straight substring match  against a bunch of fields, so you'll have to postprocess the results to make sure you're only getting users within a certain domain.